Capture https traffic of android application with certificate pinning
I need to capture https traffic of Instagram Lite app (com.instagram.lite). So I tried to use http-toolkit. I have rooted android device and used adb method, http-toolkit app on my phone tells everything ok and fake certificate needed to capture https was successfully injected. I even see traffic of certain applications, but for Instagram Lite there's only "certificate rejected" on toolkit and app won't load saying there's connection issue.
So I thought app uses certificate pinning, and went through http-toolkit official guide for such case. And when I launch this:
frida -U \
 -l ./config.js \
 -l ./native-tls-hook.js \
 -l ./android/android-certificate-unpinning.js \
 -f com.instagram.lite

App launches but then crashes on load screen. I guess it happens at the moment app tries to establish https connection. Same happens for couple of other apps, for example Discord, Spotify (which doesn't have certificate pinning at all). Here's what prints out in console:
     ____
    / _  |   Frida 16.2.1 - A world-class dynamic instrumentation toolkit
   | (_| |
    > _  |   Commands:
   /_/ |_|       help      -> Displays the help system
   . . . .       object?   -> Display information about 'object'
   . . . .       exit/quit -> Exit
   . . . .
   . . . .   More info at https://frida.re/docs/home/
   . . . .
   . . . .   Connected to SM G950F (id=192.168.8.105:39077)
Spawning `com.instagram.lite`...                                        

== Hooked native TLS lib libssl.so ==
Spawned `com.instagram.lite`. Resuming main thread!                     
[SM G950F::com.instagram.lite ]-> == Certificate unpinning completed ==
Process crashed: Bad access due to invalid address

***
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
LineageOS Version: '21.0-20240216-UNOFFICIAL-dreamlte'
Build fingerprint: 'samsung/dreamltexx/dreamlte:8.0.0/R16NW/G950FXXU1CRC7:user/release-keys'
Revision: '10'
ABI: 'arm64'
Timestamp: 2024-04-24 14:38:07.648559896+0300
Process uptime: 3s
Cmdline: com.instagram.lite
pid: 10497, tid: 10586, name: stagram.com/...  >>> com.instagram.lite <<<
uid: 10191
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0000000000000000
Cause: null pointer dereference
    x0  00000073c03f1fc8  x1  0000007703a6ebf0  x2  000000770020be50  x3  00000073c03f2230
    x4  00000073c03f21f0  x5  0000007714930358  x6  0000007714930358  x7  0000000000000000
    x8  0000000000000000  x9  0000000000000000  x10 0000000000000001  x11 0000000000006de0
    x12 0000000000000000  x13 0000000000000002  x14 0000000000000004  x15 0000000000000000
    x16 00000074504f59d8  x17 00000076fe721e00  x18 0000000000000000  x19 00000073c03f1c10
    x20 000000744ef42b28  x21 0000007703a6c440  x22 000000770020be50  x23 000000770b67d6f8
    x24 000000770020be80  x25 00000073c03f2060  x26 00000073c03f21f0  x27 0000000000000000
    x28 000000770393b680  x29 00000073c03f2000
    lr  000000744f887688  sp  00000073c03f1c10  pc  000000744f887698  pst 0000000020000000
64 total frames
backtrace:
      #00 pc 0000000000ba6698  /memfd:frida-agent-64.so (deleted)
      #01 pc 0000000000ad1f58  /memfd:frida-agent-64.so (deleted)
      #02 pc 0000000000ad4970  /memfd:frida-agent-64.so (deleted)
      #03 pc 000000000002f5e8  /system/lib64/libssl.so (bssl::ssl_verify_peer_cert(bssl::SSL_HANDSHAKE*)+316) (BuildId: 649a9806f2c0a5537a4863447dbccbf0)
      #04 pc 000000000005161c  /system/lib64/libssl.so (bssl::tls13_client_handshake(bssl::SSL_HANDSHAKE*)+2120) (BuildId: 649a9806f2c0a5537a4863447dbccbf0)
      #05 pc 000000000003107c  /system/lib64/libssl.so (bssl::ssl_client_handshake(bssl::SSL_HANDSHAKE*)+2184) (BuildId: 649a9806f2c0a5537a4863447dbccbf0)
      #06 pc 000000000002ffbc  /system/lib64/libssl.so (bssl::ssl_run_handshake(bssl::SSL_HANDSHAKE*, bool*)+364) (BuildId: 649a9806f2c0a5537a4863447dbccbf0)
      #07 pc 0000000000042378  /system/lib64/libssl.so (SSL_do_handshake+88) (BuildId: 649a9806f2c0a5537a4863447dbccbf0)
      #08 pc 0000000000042924  /system/lib64/libssl.so (ssl_read_impl(ssl_st*)+184) (BuildId: 649a9806f2c0a5537a4863447dbccbf0)
      #09 pc 0000000000042750  /system/lib64/libssl.so (SSL_read+88) (BuildId: 649a9806f2c0a5537a4863447dbccbf0)
      #10 pc 00000000000279a4  /apex/com.android.conscrypt/lib64/libjavacrypto.so (NativeCrypto_ENGINE_SSL_read_direct(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, long, _jobject*, long, int, _jobject*)+96) (BuildId: 40feb0ba06373f71e9c827cae9819953)
      #11 pc 0000000000227430  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_generic_jni_trampoline+144) (BuildId: 55b9536b61b755b7bae82e95aa498dab)
      #12 pc 000000000020a28c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (nterp_helper+3852) (BuildId: 55b9536b61b755b7bae82e95aa498dab)
      #13 pc 0000000000023d2c  /apex/com.android.conscrypt/javalib/conscrypt.jar (com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeSsl.readDirectByteBuffer+32)
      #14 pc 000000000020a2d4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (nterp_helper+3924) (BuildId: 55b9536b61b755b7bae82e95aa498dab)
      #15 pc 0000000000019088  /apex/com.android.conscrypt/javalib/conscrypt.jar (com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.readPlaintextDataDirect+12)
      #16 pc 000000000020a2d4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (nterp_helper+3924) (BuildId: 55b9536b61b755b7bae82e95aa498dab)
      #17 pc 000000000001902e  /apex/com.android.conscrypt/javalib/conscrypt.jar (com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.readPlaintextData+42)
      #18 pc 000000000020a2d4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (nterp_helper+3924) (BuildId: 55b9536b61b755b7bae82e95aa498dab)
      #19 pc 0000000000019aa6  /apex/com.android.conscrypt/javalib/conscrypt.jar (com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.unwrap+506)
      #20 pc 000000000020a9d8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (nterp_helper+5720) (BuildId: 55b9536b61b755b7bae82e95aa498dab)
      #21 pc 0000000000019c8c  /apex/com.android.conscrypt/javalib/conscrypt.jar (com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.unwrap+56)
      #22 pc 000000000020a2d4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (nterp_helper+3924) (BuildId: 55b9536b61b755b7bae82e95aa498dab)
      #23 pc 000000000001979a  /apex/com.android.conscrypt/javalib/conscrypt.jar (com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.unwrap+22)
      #24 pc 000000000020a2d4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (nterp_helper+3924) (BuildId: 55b9536b61b755b7bae82e95aa498dab)
      #25 pc 00000000000172a0  /apex/com.android.conscrypt/javalib/conscrypt.jar (com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.processDataFromSocket+140)
      #26 pc 000000000020a2d4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (nterp_helper+3924) (BuildId: 55b9536b61b755b7bae82e95aa498dab)
      #27 pc 00000000000171b0  /apex/com.android.conscrypt/javalib/conscrypt.jar (com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.-$$Nest$mprocessDataFromSocket+0)
      #28 pc 00000000002093b4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (nterp_helper+52) (BuildId: 55b9536b61b755b7bae82e95aa498dab)
      #29 pc 00000000000184f2  /apex/com.android.conscrypt/javalib/conscrypt.jar (com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket.doHandshake+110)
      #30 pc 000000000020a2d4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (nterp_helper+3924) (BuildId: 55b9536b61b755b7bae82e95aa498dab)
      #31 pc 000000000001887e  /apex/com.android.conscrypt/javalib/conscrypt.jar (com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket.startHandshake+58)
      #32 pc 000000000020a2d4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (nterp_helper+3924) (BuildId: 55b9536b61b755b7bae82e95aa498dab)
      #33 pc 000000000033d28c  /data/data/com.instagram.lite/dex/prog-8a7413981c1c734d5bdd1718740acf9144c0de9d.dex (X.0SA.AGa+3180)
      #34 pc 000000000020b0f4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (nterp_helper+7540) (BuildId: 55b9536b61b755b7bae82e95aa498dab)
      #35 pc 000000000033f880  /data/data/com.instagram.lite/dex/prog-8a7413981c1c734d5bdd1718740acf9144c0de9d.dex (X.0SE.A00+280)
      #36 pc 000000000020a2d4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (nterp_helper+3924) (BuildId: 55b9536b61b755b7bae82e95aa498dab)
      #37 pc 000000000033c3e0  /data/data/com.instagram.lite/dex/prog-8a7413981c1c734d5bdd1718740acf9144c0de9d.dex (X.0S8.AGa+928)
      #38 pc 000000000020b0f4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (nterp_helper+7540) (BuildId: 55b9536b61b755b7bae82e95aa498dab)
      #39 pc 000000000033f880  /data/data/com.instagram.lite/dex/prog-8a7413981c1c734d5bdd1718740acf9144c0de9d.dex (X.0SE.A00+280)
      #40 pc 000000000020a2d4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (nterp_helper+3924) (BuildId: 55b9536b61b755b7bae82e95aa498dab)
      #41 pc 000000000033b800  /data/data/com.instagram.lite/dex/prog-8a7413981c1c734d5bdd1718740acf9144c0de9d.dex (X.0S4.AGa+464)
      #42 pc 000000000020b0f4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (nterp_helper+7540) (BuildId: 55b9536b61b755b7bae82e95aa498dab)
      #43 pc 000000000033f880  /data/data/com.instagram.lite/dex/prog-8a7413981c1c734d5bdd1718740acf9144c0de9d.dex (X.0SE.A00+280)
      #44 pc 000000000020a2d4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (nterp_helper+3924) (BuildId: 55b9536b61b755b7bae82e95aa498dab)
      #45 pc 00000000003395e4  /data/data/com.instagram.lite/dex/prog-8a7413981c1c734d5bdd1718740acf9144c0de9d.dex (X.0RY.AGa+96)
      #46 pc 000000000020b0f4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (nterp_helper+7540) (BuildId: 55b9536b61b755b7bae82e95aa498dab)
      #47 pc 000000000033f880  /data/data/com.instagram.lite/dex/prog-8a7413981c1c734d5bdd1718740acf9144c0de9d.dex (X.0SE.A00+280)
      #48 pc 000000000020a2d4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (nterp_helper+3924) (BuildId: 55b9536b61b755b7bae82e95aa498dab)
      #49 pc 000000000032f728  /data/data/com.instagram.lite/dex/prog-8a7413981c1c734d5bdd1718740acf9144c0de9d.dex (X.0Q0.AGa+224)
      #50 pc 000000000020b0f4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (nterp_helper+7540) (BuildId: 55b9536b61b755b7bae82e95aa498dab)
      #51 pc 000000000033f880  /data/data/com.instagram.lite/dex/prog-8a7413981c1c734d5bdd1718740acf9144c0de9d.dex (X.0SE.A00+280)
      #52 pc 000000000020a2d4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (nterp_helper+3924) (BuildId: 55b9536b61b755b7bae82e95aa498dab)
      #53 pc 0000000000339252  /data/data/com.instagram.lite/dex/prog-8a7413981c1c734d5bdd1718740acf9144c0de9d.dex (X.0RX.A02+174)
      #54 pc 000000000020a2d4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (nterp_helper+3924) (BuildId: 55b9536b61b755b7bae82e95aa498dab)
      #55 pc 000000000033af56  /data/data/com.instagram.lite/dex/prog-8a7413981c1c734d5bdd1718740acf9144c0de9d.dex (X.0Ro.run+1426)
      #56 pc 00000000002b8370  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker+800) (BuildId: 033b78791329236ed3fb23a647eb6eff57adc488)
      #57 pc 00000000002b5420  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run+64) (BuildId: 033b78791329236ed3fb23a647eb6eff57adc488)
      #58 pc 0000000000160778  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (java.lang.Thread.run+72) (BuildId: 033b78791329236ed3fb23a647eb6eff57adc488)
      #59 pc 00000000002109a4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+612) (BuildId: 55b9536b61b755b7bae82e95aa498dab)
      #60 pc 00000000002539a4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+172) (BuildId: 55b9536b61b755b7bae82e95aa498dab)
      #61 pc 000000000066f48c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::CreateCallback(void*)+1404) (BuildId: 55b9536b61b755b7bae82e95aa498dab)
      #62 pc 00000000000be5c8  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+208) (BuildId: 2743e943c62322ac28a0cf6ed5e099da)
      #63 pc 000000000005b140  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64) (BuildId: 2743e943c62322ac28a0cf6ed5e099da)
***
[SM G950F::com.instagram.lite ]->

Thank you for using Frida!

I'm using Samsung Galaxy S8 with LineageOS 21 (Android 14). Is the issue with device, OS, or am I doing something wrong?

Writing universal hooks/patches for SSL libraries is pretty complicated as there are dozen of different versions. I would assume that there is a difference between the ssl library the script was developed for and your version.

If you remove scripts from the command line one by one, can you work out which script is causing this issue? You may be able to then comment out sections of script to find out what's actually failing. It's also possible the version of Frida you're using has some issue (e.g. incompatible with your specific OS somehow) in which case you'll see the app fail even if no scripts are used at all. In that case, just try a different frida server version.
